# What denominations practice "laying on of hands" so that new converts may receive the Holy Ghost, and what manifestations are usually expected?

Tags: denomination-survey, pneumatology, acts, sacraments, ritual

This question is inspired by examples in the book of Acts:

> 14 Now when the apostles in Jerusalem heard that Samaria had received the word of God, they sent them Peter and John, 15 who came down and prayed for them **that they would receive the Holy Spirit**. 16 (For He had not yet fallen upon any of them; they had simply been baptized in the name of the Lord Jesus.) 17 **Then they began laying their hands on them, and they were receiving the Holy Spirit**. 18 Now when Simon saw that **the Spirit was given through the laying on of the apostles’ hands**, he offered them money, 19 saying, “Give this authority to me as well, **so that everyone on whom I lay my hands may receive the Holy Spirit**.” 20 But Peter said to him, “May your silver perish with you, because you thought you could **acquire the gift of God** with money! 21 You have no part or share in this matter, for your heart is not right before God. 22 Therefore, repent of this wickedness of yours, and pray to the Lord that, if possible, the intention of your heart will be forgiven you. 23 For I see that you are in the gall of bitterness and in the bondage of unrighteousness.” 24 But Simon answered and said, “Pray to the Lord for me yourselves, so that nothing of what you have said may come upon me.” (Acts 8:14-24 NASB)

> Now it happened that while Apollos was in Corinth, Paul passed through the upper country and came to Ephesus, and found some disciples. 2 He said to them, “**Did you receive the Holy Spirit when you believed**?” And they said to him, “On the contrary, we have not even heard if there is a Holy Spirit.” 3 And he said, “Into what then were you baptized?” And they said, “Into John’s baptism.” 4 Paul said, “John baptized with a baptism of repentance, telling the people to believe in Him who was coming after him, that is, in Jesus.” 5 When they heard this, they were baptized in the name of the Lord Jesus. 6 **And when Paul had laid hands upon them, the Holy Spirit came on them** and they began speaking with tongues and prophesying. 7 There were about twelve men in all. (Acts 19:1-7 NASB)

> 15 But the Lord said to him, “Go, for he is a chosen instrument of Mine, to bear My name before the Gentiles and kings and the sons of Israel; 16 for I will show him how much he must suffer in behalf of My name.” 17 So Ananias departed and entered the house, **and after laying his hands on him** said, “Brother Saul, the Lord Jesus, who appeared to you on the road by which you were coming, has sent me so that you may regain your sight **and be filled with the Holy Spirit**.” 18 And immediately something like fish scales fell from his eyes, and he regained his sight, and he got up and was baptized; 19 and he took food and was strengthened. (Acts 9:15-19 NASB)

**Question**: What denominations practice "laying on of hands" so that new converts may receive the Holy Ghost, and what manifestations are usually expected when this happens?

**Note**: By manifestations I mean anything along the lines of the examples I list in [my answer](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/91819/50422) to the question [What is the evidence that someone is filled with the Holy Spirit?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/16701/50422). Alternatively, see appendix below.

---

**Appendix - Examples of manifestations I've compiled from Scripture**

Intelligence, knowledge and wisdom:

- and I have **filled him with the Spirit of God, with ability and intelligence, with knowledge and all craftsmanship**, (Exodus 31:3 ESV)
- and he has **filled him with the Spirit of God, with skill, with intelligence, with knowledge, and with all craftsmanship**, (Exodus 35:31 ESV)
- Now Joshua son of Nun was **filled with the spirit of wisdom** because Moses had laid his hands on him. So the Israelites listened to him and did what the Lord had commanded Moses. (Deuteronomy 34:9 ESV)

Power, boldness and authority:

- But as for me, **I am filled with power, with the Spirit of the Lord, and with justice and might**, to declare to Jacob his transgression, to Israel his sin. (Micah 3:8 ESV)
- But **you will receive power when the Holy Spirit has come upon you**, and you will be my witnesses in Jerusalem and in all Judea and Samaria, and to the end of the earth.” (Acts 1:8 ESV)
- Then **Peter, filled with the Holy Spirit, said to them**, “Rulers of the people and elders, (Acts 4:8 ESV)
- And when they had prayed, the place in which they were gathered together was shaken, **and they were all filled with the Holy Spirit and continued to speak the word of God with boldness**. (Acts 4:31 ESV)
- 9 But Saul, who was also called **Paul, filled with the Holy Spirit, looked intently at him** 10 **and said**, “You son of the devil, you enemy of all righteousness, full of all deceit and villainy, will you not stop making crooked the straight paths of the Lord? 11 And now, behold, the hand of the Lord is upon you, and you will be blind and unable to see the sun for a time.” Immediately mist and darkness fell upon him, and he went about seeking people to lead him by the hand. (Acts 13:9-11 ESV)

Joyful utterances:

- 41 And when Elizabeth heard the greeting of Mary, the baby leaped in her womb. **And Elizabeth was filled with the Holy Spirit**, 42 **and she exclaimed with a loud cry**, “Blessed are you among women, and blessed is the fruit of your womb! 43 And why is this granted to me that the mother of my Lord should come to me? 44 For behold, when the sound of your greeting came to my ears, the baby in my womb leaped for joy. 45 And blessed is she who believed that there would be a fulfillment of what was spoken to her from the Lord.” (Luke 1:41-45 ESV)
- 18 And do not get drunk with wine, for that is debauchery, **but be filled with the Spirit**, 19 **addressing one another in psalms and hymns and spiritual songs, singing and making melody to the Lord with your heart**, 20 giving thanks always and for everything to God the Father in the name of our Lord Jesus Christ, (Ephesians 5:18-20 ESV)
- What am I to do? I will pray with my spirit, but I will pray with my mind also; **I will sing praise with my spirit**, but I will sing with my mind also. (1 Corinthians 14:15 ESV)

Prophecy, dreams & visions:

- 17 “‘And in the last days it shall be, God declares,
  that **I will pour out my Spirit on all flesh**,
  **and your sons and your daughters shall prophesy**,
  **and your young men shall see visions**,
  **and your old men shall dream dreams**;
  18 even on my male servants and female servants
  in those days I will pour out my Spirit, **and they shall prophesy**. (Acts 2:17-18 ESV)
- But he, **full of the Holy Spirit, gazed into heaven and saw the glory of God, and Jesus standing at the right hand of God**. (Acts 7:55 ESV)
- And his father **Zechariah was filled with the Holy Spirit and prophesied**, saying, (Luke 1:67 ESV)
- Pursue love, **and earnestly desire the spiritual gifts, especially that you may prophesy**. (1 Corinthians 14:1 ESV)

Tongues:

- And they were all **filled with the Holy Spirit and began to speak in other tongues** as the Spirit gave them utterance. (Acts 2:4 ESV)
- 44 While Peter was still saying these things, **the Holy Spirit fell on all who heard the word**. 45 And the believers from among the circumcised who had come with Peter were amazed, **because the gift of the Holy Spirit was poured out even on the Gentiles**. 46 **For they were hearing them speaking in tongues and extolling God**. (Acts 10:44-45 ESV)

The fruit of the Spirit:

- 22 **But the fruit of the Spirit is love, joy, peace, patience, kindness, goodness, faithfulness**, 23 **gentleness, self-control**; against such things there is no law. 24 And those who belong to Christ Jesus have crucified the flesh with its passions and desires. (Galatians 5:22-24 ESV)

Comment: I cannot understand this question. Jesus specifically commanded baptism and the Lord's Supper as ordinances. One could also include service to one's brethren (as washing the feet or equivalent). But nowhere is there a requirement to lay on hands. At a _specific and transitional period_ in Church history, when some had only received the baptism of John (not yet receiving the Holy Spirit) there was a laying on of hands. This question appears to suggest a further ordinance - _which Jesus never commanded_ !

Comment: @NigelJ - What is your view on Hebrews 6:1-2 (YLT) *Wherefore, having left the word of the beginning of the Christ, unto the perfection we may advance, not again a foundation laying of reformation from dead works, and of faith on God, 2 of the teaching of baptisms, **of laying on also of hands**, of rising again also of the dead, and of judgment age-during,* ?

Comment: @NigelJ - Relevant question: [What is meant in the NT by the "laying on of hands"?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/496/38524)

Comment: The laying on of hands is for many purposes : the elders lay hands on the sick, hands are laid on those who go to evangelise, hands would be laid on one backslidden who repents and returns to fellowship (as the Corinthian man). But it is not an _ordinance_  ; rather a matter of fellowship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-day Saints is a faith that practices this.

The church's 4th article of faith states:

> We believe that the first principles and ordinances of the Gospel are: first, Faith in the Lord Jesus Christ; second, Repentance; third, Baptism by immersion for the remission of sins; fourth, **Laying on of hands for the gift of the Holy Ghost**.

When Jesus defined His Gospel to the Nephites He included this statement:

> 20 Now this is the commandment: Repent, all ye ends of the earth, and come unto me and be baptized in my name, **that ye may be sanctified by the reception of the Holy Ghost**, that ye may stand spotless before me at the last day. (3 Nephi 27:20)

The laying on of hands for the gift of the Holy Ghost is one of the essential [ordinances of salvation](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/manual/introduction-to-family-history-student-manual/chapter-10?lang=eng).

All of the gifts/effects described in the OP's linked answer are manifestations within the beliefs of the church (e.g. see Articles of Faith 1:7, Doctrine & Covenants 11:12-13). Another helpful list would be the fruit of the Spirit in Galatians 5--these are attitudes, behaviors, and effects coming from the Spirit:

> 22 But the fruit of the Spirit is love, joy, peace,
> longsuffering, gentleness, goodness, faith,
>
> 23 Meekness, temperance: against such there is no law.

The effects of the Spirit can include a number of outward manifestations (many of which do not come only after receipt of the gift of the Holy Ghost); the more fundamental manifestations are internal (and are processes rather than events), such as:

- The transformation of our fallen nature (see Mosiah 5:2)
- Sanctification (see 3 Nephi 27:20 above)

Answer (score 3):

At the least the Roman Catholic church and the Anglican church practice this. As part of the service of confirmation the bishop lays his hands on the candidate and says "receive the Holy Spirit".

No manifestations are expected at that immediate time.

Comment: `No manifestations are expected at that immediate time.` - Is this also the case for the Catholic Charismatic Renewal?

Comment: Agree with "No manifestations are expected at that immediate time." @SpiritRealmInvestigator  For Catholicism, Bishop Barron addresses the manifestation ***post confirmation*** in [this Word on Fire episode](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wD71MBo5gBA) minute 21:40- , "when love breaks out", when forgiveness of enemies are on display, when joy admidst suffering are evident, etc.  Non Charismatic Protestant groups agree with this description of the "manifestation" as well, happening ***post conversion***.

Comment: @GratefulDisciple - Thanks for sharing, but what about the Catholic Charismatic Renewal?

Comment: @SpiritRealmInvestigator See [my answer](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/83187/10672) on CCR's "baptism in the Holy Spirit".  As regards to manifestations, CCR specific manifestations should be seen are *optional* result of the "stirring up" post sacrament of confirmation or at best as special gifting for the benefit of others, ***not*** as required sign for someone to receive the Holy Spirit per classical Pentecostal theology.  Per 1 Cor 13, love is the primary sign of this "stirring up".

Comment: I agree with GratefulDisciple. WHen I wrote "No manifstations are expected" I meant "if there are no outward manifestations then that's perfectly fine."

Comment: @SpiritRealmInvestigator FWIW, it just happen that Roger Olson, one Protestant theology professor I highly respect for his objectivity and diverse experience, shared in his blog 2 days ago [his classical Pentecostal upbringing](https://www.patheos.com/blogs/rogereolson/2022/07/are-pentecostals-fundamentalists-part-one/), which may be of interest for you as he provides a near-ethnographic and first-person description of how various "manifestations" are expected and interpreted in various charismatic groups.

Comment: @GratefulDisciple - Thanks for sharing that as well. Would you be willing to post an answer summarizing all these articles?